# Python Requests: Can't seem to upgrade the header with csrftoken grabbed from the cookie

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, csrf

I'm having some issues inserting the {"X-CSRFTOKEN": client.cookies['ccsrftoken']} properly to my HTTP request.

The idea is to use the X-CSRFTOKEN for authentication on my firewall.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests

url = 'http://10.0.2.45/'
name = 'admin'
password = 'xyz'

#all cookies received will be stored in the session object
client = requests.session() 

print 'client headers initially: ', client.headers, '\n'


#First connection used for authentication.
login = client.post(url + '/logincheck', data="username=" + name + "&secretkey=" + password, verify = False)

#csrftoken to be inserted in the headers for next put,post,delete requests. 
This will be stored in csrftoken variable. 
print 'client cookies after login: ', client.cookies, '\n \n'
print 'csrftoken value extracted from the cookie: ', 
client.cookies['ccsrftoken'], '\n \n'

#we update the session headers with X-CSRFTOKEN 
client.headers.update({"X-CSRFTOKEN": client.cookies['ccsrftoken']})

#Simple post command (empty, just to test authentication)
api_cmdb = 'api/v2/cmdb/'
c = client.post(url + api_cmdb + 'firewall/address?vdom=root', verify = False)
```

On my firewall this will result with those three errors:

[httpsd 160 - 1502297425    error] is_valid_csrf_token[3015] -- CSRF token mismatch

[httpsd 160 - 1502297425    error] api_cmdb_execute_handler[1422] -- no valid CSRF token found

[httpsd 160 - 1502297425    error] api_return_http_result[528] -- API error 403 raised

Using Wireshark and comparisons with CURL commands (which works fine), I can see that the values inserted in the "X-CSRFTOKEN" is having a double-double quote. For example the output of client.headers.update({"X-CSRFTOKEN": client.cookies['ccsrftoken']}):

```
CaseInsensitiveDict({'X-CSRFTOKEN': '"6C369B52B8211679DF2AC9676945CC"', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, compress', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.6 Linux/3.4.0+'})
```

Whereas this value should simply be inserted without a second "set of quote".

Any idea how to correct this?

Many thanks

> here is the output of client.cookies from a new sess:

```
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>
[<Cookie APSCOOKIE_9539865664988587055="Era%3D0%26Payload%3DGAytA5jio‌​AyuHvus1rw3dfKdzWrJm‌​3CyraiFVxenLzBRb6qHL‌​qlcnIIUaZz5ZJma%0A7M‌​yKPN+4hgCPi8+yGeMhLd‌​TVAAlG0zHmtPw7y6v+nr‌​JVc1g7NZisFowGZ4TZac‌​fL%0AaiMjHE+0MuJLA7r‌​6COt4G+ikwMWlh8YWO0R‌​F5rvE0t6nYX%2FLvla1y‌​FjKy5Odu7kA%0AeewY6s‌​B0zbybh6eRSWQf5Q%3D%‌​3D%0A%26AuthHash%3DL‌​olbIaWtHofmkwMG1Fh6g‌​Wc6K%2FkA%0A"  
for 10.0.2.45/>, 
<Cookie ccsrftoken="2A28F281C83FF4B3235134C335D53B5" for 10.0.2.45//>, 
<Cookie ccsrftoken_9539865664988587055="2A28F281C83FF4B3235134C335D5‌​3B5" for 10.0.2.45//>]>
```

Comment: What is the output from the line where you print `client.cookies` after login?

Comment: Hello @Lukas,
from a new sess:
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[<Cookie APSCOOKIE_9539865664988587055="Era%3D0%26Payload%3DGAytA5jioAyuHvus1rw3dfKdzWrJm3CyraiFVxenLzBRb6qHLqlcnIIUaZz5ZJma%0A7MyKPN+4hgCPi8+yGeMhLdTVAAlG0zHmtPw7y6v+nrJVc1g7NZisFowGZ4TZacfL%0AaiMjHE+0MuJLA7r6COt4G+ikwMWlh8YWO0RF5rvE0t6nYX%2FLvla1yFjKy5Odu7kA%0AeewY6sB0zbybh6eRSWQf5Q%3D%3D%0A%26AuthHash%3DLolbIaWtHofmkwMG1Fh6gWc6K%2FkA%0A" for 10.0.2.45/>, <Cookie ccsrftoken="2A28F281C83FF4B3235134C335D53B5" for 10.0.2.45//>, <Cookie ccsrftoken_9539865664988587055="2A28F281C83FF4B3235134C335D53B5" for 10.0.2.45//>]>

Comment: It's not clear which Output is from `client.cookies['ccsrftoken']`. Please [Edit] your Question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this.

It simply needed a string slice.

If a = client.cookies['ccsrftoken']
then csrftoken = a[1:-1]

This works fine after testing.